# Finding patterns on strings on Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

My function was suposed to receive a large string, go through it, and find the maximum number of times the pattern "AGATC" repeats consecutively. Regardless of what I feed this function, my return is always 1.

```
def agatc(s):
    maxrep = 0
    temp = 0
    for i in range(len(s) - 4):
        if s[i] == "A" and s[i + 1] == "G" and s[i + 2] == "A" and s[i + 3] == "T" and s[i + 4] == "C":
            temp += 1
            print(i)
            i += 3
        else:
            if temp > maxrep:
                maxrep = temp
            temp = 0
    return maxrep
```

Also tried initializing the for loop with `(0, len(s) - 4, 1)`, got the same return.

I though the problem might be in adding 3 to the `i` variable (apparently it wasn't), so I added `print(i)` to see what was happening. I got the following:

```
45
1938
2049
2195
2952
2957
2962
2967
2972
2977
2982
2987
2992
2997
3002
3007
3012
3017
3022
3689
4754
```

Comment: can you give sample input for `s`

Comment: Side note: you can use `if s[i:i+5] == "AGATC"`.

Comment: Which implies that you probably wanna change `range(len(s) - 4)` to `range(len(s) - 5)`.

Comment: i += 3 won't do anything, it's immediately replaced by the next value from the range by the loop itself.

Comment: It's because you don't let `maxrep` be any bigger than `1`... Once you found a match, you do `maxrep = temp` but then initialize `temp = 0`. Now it will never hold that `temp > maxrep` so you will never change `maxrep` which is now `1`... Why do you even need `temp` and the `else` clause? Why not just `maxrep += 1` once the condition is true?

Comment: @goodvibration your last comment is not correct. `range` is exclusive so `range(len(s)-4)` should be what he is looking for

Comment: @Tomerikoo If my string was "AGATCAGATCAAAAAGATC", My maxrep should be 2. I need to count the maximum number of times it repeats after itself without having anything else in between.

Comment: In that case the answer you accepted doesn't give what you want

Comment: @Tomerikoo he pointed out my mistake, which was using for instead of while. After changing that, my code works perfectly now!

Comment: If I understand you correctly, for the string `s = "AGATCAGATCAAAAAGATCA"` you would expect to get 2, while the code below gives 3. This code simply counts total occurrences, not consecutive repeats

Comment: @Tomerikoo Yes. But his answer was what made me see what I had done wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this way you can find the number of overlapping matches:

```
def agatc(s):
    temp = 0
    for i in range(len(s) - len("AGATC") + 1):
        if s[i:i+len("AGATC")] == "AGATC":
            temp += 1
    return temp
```

If you want to find non-overlapping matches:

```
def agatc(s):
    temp = 0
    i = 0
    while i < len(s) - len("AGATC") + 1:
        if s[i:i+len("AGATC")] == "AGATC":
            temp += 1
            i += len("AGATC")
        else:
            i += 1
    return temp
```

Comment: Thank you! So I can't use for loops as I did in C, right? It's not possible to change the value of i in the middle of the iteration?

Comment: In C you perform an operation at the end of the for cycle body (for example, I++). In python, first all the values are generated (with range(n)), that is before the for cycle begins, and then i takes all those values. So even if you change i within the body, it has no effect on range values.

Comment: `len(s) - len("AGATC")` is wrong. Try `s = "AGATCAGATCAAAAAGATCA"`

Comment: The difference is 15. Therefore the last valid index is 14, because i is strictly less than 15

Comment: exactly, so you skip the last letter. You would expect the last index to be 15

Comment: My point was that your answer doesn't do what OP asked for. He asked for the max consecutive repeat. But it also fails to do what you think it does which count the total occurrences. My example was wrong, try `s = "AGATCAGATCAAAAAGATC"`. This will output `2` while the count is `3`

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution with module **re**

```
import re

s = 'FGHAGATCATCFJSFAGATCAGATCFHGH'
match = re.finditer('(?P<name>AGATC)+', s)
max_len = 0
result = tuple()
for m in match:
    l = m.end() - m.start()
    if l > max_len:
        max_len = l
        result = (m.start(), m.end())

print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would use regular expressions. But if you do not want that, you could use the str.find() method. Here is my solution:

```
def agatc(s):
    cnt = 0
    findstr='aga'                             # pattern you are looking for
    for i in range(len(s)):
        index = s.find(findstr)
        if index != -1:
            cnt+=1
            s = s[index+1:]                   # overlapping matches
            # s = s[index+len(findstr):]      # non-overlapping matches only
            print(index, s)                   # just to see what happens
    return cnt
```

Answer (score 0):

This function counts the greatest amount of consecutive `'AGATC'`s in a string and returns the amount:

```
def agatc(s):
    w = "AGATC"
    maxrep = [m.start() for m in re.finditer(w,s)] # The beginning index fror each AGATC
    c = ''
    for i,v in enumerate(maxrep):
        if i < len(maxrep)-1:
            if v+5 == maxrep[i+1]:
                c+='y'
            else:
                c+='n'

    return len(max(c.split('n')))+1

print(agatc("oooooooooAGATCooooAGATCAGATCAGATCAGATCooooooAGATCAGATC"))
```

Output:

```
4
```